# CSRF Error occurs even with the necessary token

Tags: django, csrf

I'm trying to make a simple logIn page. I understand the concept of CSRF but even with a token and an import and the necessary middleware, I'm still getting a 403 (forbidden)error.

Please help! What am I doing wrong?

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

def login_user(request):
   state = "Please log in below..."
   username = password = ''
   c = {}
   c.update(csrf(request))
   if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                state = "You're successfully logged in!"
            else:
                state = "Your account is not active, please contact the site admin."
        else:
            state = "Your username and/or password were incorrect."

    return render_to_response('auth.html',{'state':state, 'username': username}, c)
```

auth.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Log in</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <style>
 body{
     font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
     font-size: 12px;
 }
 </style>
 </head>

<body>
    {{ state }}
    <form action="/login/" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
        {% if next %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
        {% endif %}
        username: 
        <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ username}}" /><br />
        password:
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />

        <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: code sourced from http://solutoire.com/2009/02/26/django-series-1-a-custom-login-page/

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot of unnecessary code in that login_user function. You don't need to add the csrf_token manually; but if you do, you do it in the template context dictionary itself, not in a separate parameter.

What you should do is remove the two lines  `c = {}` and `c.update(csrf(request))`, and at the end of the function do this instead:

```
return render(request, 'auth.html',{'state':state, 'username': username})
```

Comment: I tried and unfortunately still the same error. Is there definitely nothing else i could possibly missing in settings or urls? As far as i know, Ive got everything the documentation requires.https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/

Comment: Is that definitely the view that is responsible for initially rendering the login form, before the post?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. Is it worth changing the render statement to `return render_to_response(‘auth.html’,{‘state':state, ‘username': username}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))` ?

Comment: ^ just gives me a syntax error "Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /Users/jeremylovemore/Desktop/conference/src/logIn/views.py on line 24"

Comment: Because you're using `‘` instead of `'`. But the code itself should make no difference.